# MapPageRoute() vs. Site's Root Directory Repeatedly Loads Target Resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, global-asax

I have the following line in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
routes.MapPageRoute( "Resorts", "{resortname}", "~/Pages/ViewResort.aspx" );
```

The intention is to allow a request like:

```
www.mysite.com/some-resort-name
```

to load this resource (more or less)

```
www.mysite.com/Pages/ViewResort.aspx?resortname=some-resort-name
```

This behavior works fine. However, I'm noticing that `ViewResort.aspx` is being loaded *every* time any resource is requested, presumably because my route doesn't contain a literal path segment, like this alternative would:

```
routes.MapPageRoute( "Resorts", "Resort/{resortname}", "~/Pages/ViewResort.aspx" );
```

My client is insistent that the only thing after the hostname in the URL be the resort name, so going with the alternate route is not a possibility.

So my question is: is there something special one needs to do to the `RouteUrl` when it refers to the site's root directory? Failing that, is there a particular pattern that can be implemented on the target page (`ViewResort.aspx` in this case) to prevent it from being loaded and discarded with each page request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is acting as a catch-all. In situations like this, you'll need to provide specific routes *before* the catch-all route in order to give the proper responses for those specific routes. In other words, the only routes that should get through to your catch-all are routes that *must* redirect to Pages/ViewResort.aspx.